# Can not find resource editor in design tab

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been using android studio 4.0 and following a **[tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-linear-layout/index.html#4)** from codelab. I can not find three dots for clicking to open resurce editor. I am a newbie. Could you please help me to get through this. Unless i have to change every attribute settings manually. Thank you.

**This one from tutorial**

[image: This one from tutorial]

**On Android Studio 4.0**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to select any View in the editor, then you will find this attributes link

[image]

Then for every attribute at the end, you will have this icon

[image]

This will open Resource Dialog for you